# How do I handle a situation where SSL/TLS certificate errors keep happening on HttpClient even when I override the delegate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code snippet. I think that I have successfully overriden SSL/TLS check for this URL, but I still get the expception. What I have done wrong?

I also know my ASYNC logic is bad, dealing with that later! :)

```
            filename = uri.LocalPath;
        using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())
        {
            handler.UseCookies = false;
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie",
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"].ToString());

                client.BaseAddress = uri;
                var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
```

One the URLs I am trying to call is: https://cdn.misoenergy.org/20200128%20SSPM%20Item%2001c%20Agenda421035.pdf

The error message I get is:

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: Just to be sure, what exception are you getting? Sometimes it's not the certificate that causes the problem, but for instance a mismatch between supported protocols on the client vs server.

Comment: Without the error message its pretty much a guessing game. I would start with removing "handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;"

Comment: I think I may have it. I think our CDN doesn't accept SSL3.0 anymore, adding this seems to fix the download.

                handler.UseCookies = false;
                handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;